# SASS compiler on Windows is horribly slow

Tags: windows, performance, sass

I have problems compiling SASS on my Windows Environnement.

The website/files is on a mapped network drive, which causes horrible delay in compilation (more than 100 secs)

I use Grunt to compile the SASS files. I was using grunt-contrib-sass but recently switched to grunt-sass which uses libsass (c++) instead of Ruby/Gem

Even after switching from grunt-contrib-sass to grunt-sass, the compilation is slow.

I tried to compile directly with `sass --watch src:dest` but it's still slow.

I also tried several GUI (Koala, Scout, Prepos) but it's still slow.

I think the main issue is because I'm compiling files on the network drive.

Any ideas that could help speed it up? Maybe I should get a Mac...

Answer (score 0):

If it makes you feel any better, I had the same problem on a Mac at a previous job. I think your best bet would be to actually compile on your local machine then use an automated tool to copy the new compiled file over to the appropriate place on the network drive. Since you're already using Grunt, [grunt-multisync](https://github.com/jaetask/multisync) may provide a good workflow for you.